# Spring WebSocket UserDestinationMessageHandler sending message to unauthenticated user

Tags: spring-websocket

I am using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE.

- An **unauthenticated** client is subscribing to "`/user/topic/qqq`".
- This is converted to `/topic/qqq-user{sessionId}`
- The server sends a message to this user, as following:

Like:

```
.convertAndSend("/topic/qqq-user{sessionId}", "Message");
```

and this **WORKS** as expected.

- But, when the server tries to send the message

Like:

.convertAndSendToUser({sessionId}, "/topic/qqq", "Message");

but this does **NOT WORK**, and results:

```
UserDestinationMessageHandler: - No user destinations found for /user/{sessionId}/topic/qqq
```

The question is:

1. Is not the task of **UserDestinationMessageHandler** converting the destination from `/user/{sessionId}/topic/qqq` to `/topic/qqq-user{sessionId}` ?
2. If it is, it is not working because the client is not authenticated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just

`.convertAndSendToUser({sessionId},"/qqq", "Message");`

Then the client will subscribe as:

`client.subscribe("/user/{sessionId}/qqq", callback)`